# Screen Time is not asking for a passcode in Ventura

Tags: parental-controls, screen-time

I've setup Screen Time on my laptop so that Down Time comes on at 1am. It's password protected... but whenever I open an app that's supposedly not allowed, I'm prompted with this window:

[image]

If I just click, "Ignore Limit for Today", the app opens up immediately. No request for the passcode.

I've tried restarting. Turning it off and on again. I don't understand why this basic feature has suddenly stopped working?!

Can anyone help?

Comment: You stated it “suddenly stopped working.”  Was this after an update or did you make any changes to settings?

Comment: @Allan After a migration to a new Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have Screen Time ask for the Screen Time password when asking for more time. For this, you have to enable "Block at Downtime" and "Block at end of limit".

To enable "Block at Downtime", go to *System Settings > Screen Time > Downtime* and enable "**Block at Downtime**". (See [Manage downtime in Screen Time on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/manage-downtime-in-screen-time-mchl69510069/mac) for more info and guidance)

To enable "Block at end of limit", go to *System Settings > Screen Time > App Limits* and enable "**Block at end of limit**". (See [Use Screen Time on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210387) for more info and guidance)

---

**Note:** Of course those two parameters won't appear if you haven't set a *Screen Time password*.

**Note 2:** "Block at Downtime" will work on categories or apps (1) for which this setting is enabled or (2) when they are controlled by Downtime<sup>1</sup> (not an App Limit).

**Note 3:** "Block at end of limit" will work on categories or apps (1) for which this setting is enabled or (2) when they are controlled by an App Limit<sup>2</sup> (not Downtime).

<sup><sup>1</sup>To see your Downtime schedule, go to *System Settings > Screen Time > Downtime*.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>To see the App Limits you have set, go to *System Settings > Screen Time > App Limits*.</sup>